# My express react App keeps on giving me the error that It cannot find my api

Tags: reactjs, express

I am building a React + express website which allows users to make webProjects. It displays these projects in a table. The user is able to add, and edit the web projects. I am adding a function which allows the user to delete an item by pressing the delete button next to the items. My function works in Postman but I cant get it to work when I press the button in the frontend. When the button is pressed it says that it cannot read the undefined reading of map, but when I reload the page, my item is deleted from the table. But only the predefined webprojects do that, If I add a project and then press delete on that added project it says that it failed to load the resource or it just says "DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/delete 404 (Not Found)"

```
TableData.js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export const TableData = ({ projectData, fillInput, setContent, selectedProject }) => {
  console.log(projectData)

  const [deleteID, setDeleteID] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedProject) {
        setDeleteID(selectedProject.ID);
        console.log(selectedProject)
    }
}, [selectedProject])

//This is a function which deals with deleting a webProject
const deleteItem = (projectId) => {
  fetch("/api/delete", {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: projectId }) // ID to delete
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((updatedProjects) => {
    console.log(updatedProjects);
    setContent({ projectData: updatedProjects }); // This Code for update the state
  })
}

  return (
    <div>
        <div className="tableheading">
        <strong>My Projects</strong>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>URL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {projectData.map((projectData, index) => (
                <tr key={projectData.ID}>
                    <td>{projectData.ID}</td>
                    <td>{projectData.TITLE}</td>
                    <td>{projectData.DESCRIPTION}</td>
                    <td>{projectData.URL}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" onClick={() => fillInput(projectData)}>edit</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button" onClick={() => deleteItem(projectData.ID)}>Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  ) 
}



 App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { TableData } from './components/TableData'
import FormData from './components/FormData'



function App() {

  const [content, setContent] = useState({ webProjects: []});
  const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then((response) => response.json()
    ).then((response) => {setContent(response)}
    )
  }, [])


  const  fillInput = (project) => {
    setSelectedProject(project)
  }

  const  fillInputId = (project) => {
    setSelectedProject(project.ID)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TableData 
        projectData={content.webProjects}
        fillInput={fillInput}
        setContent={setContent}
        selectedProject={selectedProject}
        setSelectedProject={setSelectedProject}
      />
      {/* The props are sent to provide the FormData component with information 
      about the currently selected project which will be used when editing a project. */}
      <FormData 
        selectedProject={selectedProject}
        setSelectedProject={setSelectedProject}
        fillInputId={fillInputId}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


let webProjects = [

  {
    ID: 1,
    TITLE: "React Game",
    DESCRIPTION: "Tic tac toe game created using Create React App",
    URL: "http://someURL/myapp/game/",
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    TITLE: "Online Store",
    DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Javascript.",
    URL: "http://someURL2/shop/index",
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    TITLE: "Online Store",
    DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Angular.",
    URL: "http://someURL3/shop2/index",
  }
]

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  //send the array to hte frontend
  res.json({ webProjects });
})



app.post("/api/create", (req, res) => {
  //used to create a new webproject 
  newObj = {
    ID: req.body.ID,
    TITLE: req.body.TITLE,
    DESCRIPTION: req.body.DESCRIPTION,
    URL: req.body.URL,
  };


  webProjects.push(newObj);
  res.json({ webProjects });


})


app.put("/api/put", (req, res) => {
  // used req.body to get the data from the frontend
  const id = parseInt(req.body.id);
  const newData = req.body;
  let tempIndex = webProjects.findIndex((elem) => elem.ID == id);
  //database ID of data which is going to be updated
  if (tempIndex > -1) {
    webProjects[tempIndex].TITLE = newData.title;
    webProjects[tempIndex].DESCRIPTION = newData.description;
    webProjects[tempIndex].URL= newData.url;

    return res.status(200).json(webProjects);
  } else {
    return res.status(404).json({
      msg: "ID not found!",
    });
  }
});

app.delete("/api/delete", (req, res) => {
  const projectId = parseInt(req.body.id);
    const projectIndex = webProjects.findIndex(project => project.ID === projectId);

    if (projectIndex === -1) {
        return res.status(404).send("Project not found");
    }

    webProjects.splice(projectIndex,1);
  //res.send(`The item was successfully deleted`)
    res.send(webProjects);
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 5000")
})
```

Comment: So what happens when you press delete in your app? "It doesn't work" is not enough information for anyone here to help you.

Comment: We need to see more code about the server.js routes implementation

Answer (score 0):

DELETE request, it's generally recommended to use query parameters or include the data in the URL itself.

Use this

```
fetch(`/api/delete/${projectId}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        //body: JSON.stringify({ id: projectId }) // ID to delete
      })


app.delete("/api/delete/:projectId", (req, res) => {
  const {projectId}= parseInt(req.params);
    const projectIndex = webProjects.findIndex(project => project.ID === projectId);

    if (projectIndex === -1) {
        return res.status(404).send("Project not found");
    }

    webProjects.splice(projectIndex,1);
  //res.send(`The item was successfully deleted`)
    res.send(webProjects);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I implemented the code that you have given, however when I use it I still get an error code when I press the delete button. The error message us: DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/delete/5 404 (Not Found)

Comment: fetch(`backend server base url  ex. http://localhost:5000/api/delete/5 /api/delete/${projectId}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        //body: JSON.stringify({ id: projectId }) // ID to delete
      })